# Write down a basis for W?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let W ⊂ M2(R) be the subspace of all matrices such that the entries of
the first column add up to zero. Write down a basis for W.

i thinks Any two linearly independent matrices
in W will be the answer.

Is it corrects ..pliz tell me

Answer (score 3):

1. A basis is a set of independent vectors such that every element in the space can be written as a linear combination of basis vectors.
2. I'm not sure what size your matrices are, but suppose they're 2x2:

$$\begin{bmatrix}-&-\\-&-\end{bmatrix}$$

3. We allow the right column to be anything; therefore, let us include basis elements that allow us to freely set the values in the right column:
   $$B_1 \equiv\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0&0\end{bmatrix} \qquad B_2 \equiv\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}  $$
4. As for the first column, we must have the sum of the first and second elements be zero. For a 2x2 matrix, this means that if $a$ is the value of the upper-left entry, then $-a$ must be the element in the lower-left entry. Hence we add a third basis element:

   $$B_3 \equiv \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
5. This completes the basis: any member of this space looks like:
   $$\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ -a & c\end{bmatrix} = a \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\-1&0\end{bmatrix} + b\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix} + c \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} = aB_3 + bB_1 + cB_2$$